# In other languages I can do a Boolean test on an integer. In Java, can I say something like:

Tags: java, boolean

In other languages, I can do a Boolean test on an integer. In Java, can I say something like:

```
int x = 0;
while(x){ }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't exist, but you can use `while (x == 0)` as well

Comment: You can write `while (x == 0)` (will execute as long as x is 0) or `while (x != 0)` (will execute as long as x is not 0)

Comment: no. An if or while requires a boolean expression.

Comment: No, you can't "test" an int directly. I'd even say that it's not right for Java numerics to expose bitwise operations, but they did it anyway back then, so meh.

Comment: "can I say something like" - why don't you try running such code and see yourself? It would take less than 2 min to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JLS 14.12. The while Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12)

> The while statement executes an Expression and a Statement repeatedly until the value of the Expression is false.
>   WhileStatement:
>       `while ( Expression ) Statement`
>       `WhileStatementNoShortIf:`
>       `while ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf`
>
> **The *Expression* must have type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error occurs.**

For why its not allowed check [Why exactly does Java not allow numeric conditionals like if(5) { …} if C does?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348783/why-exactly-does-java-not-allow-numeric-conditionals-like-if5-if-c-does)

Answer (score 0):

No, You can only have a boolean expression inside the condition of the while loop. This is common to if-else also.

You can have an expression like `while (x == 0)` or any valid expression you like.
`while (x)` is not allowed.